# PHP Two functions with same name

Tags: php

How would I include two functions with the same name in a php file?

I have two files:

file1.php which includes

> function getResidentCount()
> {}
>
> function getResidentData()
> {}

file2.php also includes

> function getResidentCount()
> {}
>
> function getResidentData()
> {}

I need file3.php to include all of these functions since each one is used to calculate different resident counts and data.

Any idea how I can include both of these files in one file.  I cannot change the original files (they are in production for a live app).

Thanks,
Claudia

Comment: Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: put them in a separate file and include that

Comment: A quick workaround could be using namespaces.

Comment: that would need the include files to be modified though?

Answer (score 4):

This is evil. I only offer it as an exercise.

```
include('file1.php');
//include('file2.php'); 
$php=file_get_contents("file2.php");
$php=str_replace('getResidentCount', 'file2GetResidentCount', $php);
$php=str_replace('getResidentData', 'file2GetResidentData', $php);
eval($php);
```

Now you can call the duplicated function with a different name!

Do not do this. It's just an idea :)

An alternative would be use the [APD extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php), which lets you rename functions. Include the first file, rename its functions with [rename_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php), then include the second file.

Really, you should probably take a deep breath, delay what you're doing, and refactor what you have. Learn from it and change your practices so that it can't happen again. [Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) might help you, a more object oriented approach might also.

Comment: Nice solutions, regarding the dirtyness of the problem itself. :)

Comment: When I call the 'file2GetResidentCount', I get a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function SignificantgetResidentCount() ".

Comment: that's because it's a fairly naive search and replace - I'm guessing SignificantgetResidentCount is in different include file, but file2 will be trying to call Significantfile2GetResidentCount - refine the replacement, e.g. replace 'function getResidentCount' with 'function file2GetResidentCount'. Rinse, and repeat until it works. I feel bad just clarifying this. It's almost like you're going to use it...

Comment: Is it possible to require one file, then undefine the functions once you're done using them. Then require the second file?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to include both files as is. Doing so would result in `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare ...`.

**Paul Dixon** has provided a work around if you can't otherwise *clean up* your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to use one of the functions per run of the script then you can use conditional inclusion:

```
if (some_condition) {
    require_once 'file1.php';
} else {
    require_once 'file2.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a solution to a similar answer, I was surprised to see nobody mentioned the [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

**file1.php**

```
$myfunction=function($val){
    //do something with val
    );
```

**file2.php**

```
$myfunction=function($val){
    //do something with val
    );
```

**file3.php**

```
for($i=1;$i<3;++$i){
    include_once('file'.$i.'.php');
    $result[$i]=$myfunction($val);
    }
```

The only drawback in this solution is that `$myfunction` gets overwritten, so it's not re-usable.

But this could perhaps be solved (not tested) with `clone`:

```
$allfunctions=[];    
for($i=1;$i<3;++$i){
        include_once('file'.$i.'.php');
        $allfunctions[$i]=clone $myfunction();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up nesting my functions for the page where I needed both sets of these functions.  Thanks to all for your help.